# Texture becomes white box when drawing it?

Tags: c++, sprites, sfml

My problem is that when I try to render my `sf::Sprite` it only renders a white box in my window.

I did some reading on this and couldn't really find anything that helped.

Some said that it's because of  the `sf::Texture` variable being in a local scope but mine is in a .h file, which isn't a local scope (I think, at least...)

Someone also mentioned `std::vectors` somehow destroying the `sf::Texture` 's,
but my `sf::Texture` is not in a `std::vector`.

However my class which contains `sf::Texture` is a object inside a `std::vector` but I don't know if that matters or not.

---

In my `Sprite.h` I have defined my `sf::Sprite`, `sf::Texture` and `sf::Image` like this :

```
sf::Sprite sprite;
sf::Texture texture;
sf::Image image;
```

and I load an image in like this :

```
if (!image.loadFromFile(PATH))
    std::cout << "Could not load image file : " << PATH << std::endl;

texture.loadFromImage(image);
sprite.setTexture(texture);
```

I render the `sf::Sprite` like this :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++)
    {
        entities[i].Draw();
    }
```

Lastly, here's my `std::vector` of my "sprite objects".

```
std::vector<Sprite>entities;
entities.push_back(Sprite(&window, sf::Vector2f(100, 100), 0, "Res/Images/Face.bmp"));
```

---

The picture file is a `.bmp` file, and the path to the file is valid.

---

(I did check both google and this forum for posts like this but none of them helped me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Sprite` class contains a `sf::Texture` object which is moved by the `std::vector<Sprite>` container.

You're still placing `sf::Texture` inside a `std::vector`, just indirectly.

When the `std::vector` gets resized `Sprite` objects get copied to a new larger buffer at new addresses. But the texture pointer inside `sf::Sprite` still points to the old address where the `sf::Texture` used to be originally.

You can fix this by using an `std::vector<Sprite *>` instead which will copy the pointers to objects rather than the objects themselves.

```
std::vector<Sprite *> entities;
```

and allocate your Sprite objects on the heap as such:

```
entities.push_back(new Sprite(&window, sf::Vector2f(100, 100), 0, "Res/Images/Face.bmp"));
```

(Note the **new** keyword above.)

To destroy:

```
delete entities[i]; // Delete first
entities.erase(entities.begin()+i); // remove from array (std::vector)
```

to draw:

```
for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); ++i)
{
    entities[i]->Draw();
}
```

(Note the **->** operator instead of **.** operator above. And use the prefix operator ++i whenever possible)

This will make sure every `Sprite` object stay in the same spot in memory once created. Only pointers to them get stored inside the `std::vector`.

It also makes adding and removing objects faster as less data is moved around.

You just have to remember to **delete** the `Sprite` objects before erasing the entry in `entities` or you will leak memory.